# I can't access any info in $current_user

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm running a site on WP, and it won't let me access information from the global variable $current_user, after I run get_currentuserinfor().

I have a php file in my theme (not a wordpress-specific file), and in that file, have the following:

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('../../../wp-blog-header.php');

print_r ($current_user);
?>
```

Then, in wp-blog-header, I have the following:

```
<?php
/**
 * Loads the WordPress environment and template.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

if ( !isset($wp_did_header) ) {
    $wp_did_header = true;
    require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );
    wp();
  require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/template-loader.php' );
  global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();
}
?>
```

When I try to access my php file in a browser, I get the following:
WP_User Object ( [data] => [ID] => 0 [id] => 0 [caps] => Array ( ) [cap_key] => [roles] => Array ( ) [allcaps] => Array ( ) [first_name] => [last_name] => [filter] => )

I would appreciate any help you all have!

**Edit**

When I am accessing the file in Safari & Firefox, after I have logged in, it's working correctly. But not in Chrome for some reason (which is what I develop in). I tried clearing all of my browser data in Chrome, and still no luck.

Comment: To ask the obvious question: were you logged in to your Wordpress when you checked that output?

Comment: Hey John, haha - yes I am! On my index.php page, I have a conditional seeing if the user is logged in. If so, it displays a "Edit your profile" link, and upon clicking that, takes me to the wp-admin/profile.php page without needing to sign in.

Comment: This is weird - after testing it in Safari and Firefox, it's working perfectly, but Chrome still shows that empty object. See my edit above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your own PHP file ensure that $current_user is defined as global.

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
global $current_user; # <-- Add this
require('../../../wp-blog-header.php');

print_r ($current_user);
?>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the attempt to help, but that didn't change anything. I appreciate your time, though!

Comment: Well that is part of the problem I think. Try this inside wp-blog-header.php remove the `if (!isset($wp_did_header))`. Simply call `global $current_user; get_currentuserinfo();`. See if that works. My guess is the function is not getting called inside that file.

Comment: I took `global $current_user; get_currentuserinfo();` out of the IF statement to see if it would return anything, and still - no luck. Hmm.

Answer (score 1):

It lets you access $current_user, because it's showing up as an object

```
 WP_User Object ( [data] => [ID] => 0 [id] => 0 [caps] => Array ( ) [cap_key] => [roles] => Array ( ) [allcaps] => Array ( ) [first_name] => [last_name] => [filter] => )
```

Make sure you're logged in when trying to access this file

Comment: Hi, that makes sense. Your response got me thinking, and I tested it in some other browsers. For some reason, Chrome is being weird (firefox & safari are both working great). I cleared all of my data in Chrome, and still not sure what's up. Thank you for your help, though!

Comment: If I helped you, please help me: **[accept my answer](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6V5xR.gif)** (click on that link if you're not sure how to do so)